# Analysis crossover clinical trial

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, crossover-study

I have data from a six-sequence 3-drug 3-phase crossover trial that had a 7-day baseline period pre-study (used to generate mean baseline value).  My outcome is a non-parametric continuous variable that becomes parametric with a log transformation. The outcome is an ocular measure that is measured in both eyes, 4 times a day in 9 individuals.
Outcome:TP
My fixed effects are: Phase (I,II,III), Day(1-7), Drug (A,B,C), BaselineTP + CarryOver

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to clarify what it is you want help with. Two suggestions though: (1) A variable can be non-normal, but you can't say that it is non-parametric. Models can be non-parametric (though usually these are still semi-parametric). Likewise, a variable can become approximately normal after transformation, but you can't prove that it is now normal. (2) You model several variables both as fixed and random, this doesn't seem right. You also don't need to do `1|ID/Eye`, when you specify `1|ID`, the fixed effect of `Eye` will be correctly estimated for IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Parametric does not mean normally distributed. In fact, a parametric model for the response could be log-normal--in which case the logged response would be normal. Even if exploratory analyses suggest the log transform makes a normal-looking response, one does not justify fitting a model because the proposed change of variable makes the outcome normal. A log transform is used because it is a geometric mean difference that you are interested in reporting. For instance, if you fit the linear model:

$$E[\log Y|X] = \alpha + \beta X$$

You would report and interpret $\exp(\beta)$ as a percentage-difference in response comparing groups differing by one unit in $X$. This is often the correct model for analyzing concentrations, etc. But actually a log transform enjoys a wide variety of applications, especially in the context of a GLM where one might analyze a host of outcomes like test scores, proportions, or ordinal scaled values.

In an intent-to-treat analysis, you analyze patients as-randomized. That means the subject who is randomized to treatment A at time 1, treatment B at time 2, and treatment C at time 3 will have those assignments analyzed in whatever fashion was prespecified as part of a statistical analysis plan. A per-protocol analysis

A typical linear model for a change-from-baseline analysis is the ANCOVA specification where the post-baseline response is taken as an outcome and the baseline response is adjusted-for as a covariate.

If the response is assessed at multiple post-baseline time points, correlated data models may be used. An appropriate method for repeated measures should be used like a generalized least squares model, linear mixed model with random intercept, or generalized estimating equations.

If one adjusts for time, lagged effects, and possibly participant level effects, it is possible that the data may be conditionally independent (or approximately so) and so correlated data models don't need to be used. There are a few exploratory analyses that can assess that.